# Mysqli_num_rows returns invalid count when we use mysqli_query multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

I am calling one procedure which will return single row and trying to print the number of returned. it will return 1. when I call the second procedure which will also return single row and try to print the count, it will return 2!! . it is adding record count with previous record count each time when we call $db->query(). why record count is not coming properly? what could be the reason? how to get record count respective of each query?

```
$db=new mysqli('localhost','root','','dbname');
$res=$db->query("call Proc_EmpLeaveDet_Fetch('a-000','','')");
$db->next_result();
echo $res->num_rows;

$ressearch=$db->query("call Proc_EmpLeaveDet_Fetch('a-000','35','LeaveCode')");
$db->next_result();
echo $ressearch->num_rows;
```

Comment: There are few bugs in your code. First '$empcode' will not be actual value of $empcode.  next_result() is used with mysql_multi_query since you are not using multi query so you can avoid $db->next_result();

Comment: I have provided employee code in the first procedure call.I have used        db->next_result() because each procedure will return number of records. if i dont use it, second query will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this and this might be related to the specific version of PHP you're using; which you didn't specify. However, I suspect you can fix this by explicitly closing the previous resultset, and [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#102904) has a few related issues you might otherwise run into.

I noticed you're also using [$db->next_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.next-result.php) which is meant to be used with multi-queries. Since you're not using those; the next_result call is useless and should be removed.

Comment: i am writing number of lines codes dependent of each records set after the procedure call which i hv not provided here. so i cannot close $res recordset before creating $ressearch.

Comment: Like I said; running multiple stored procedures simultaneously is known to cause issues; try to change your code so you don't need to do that

Comment: i have tried by closing the first resultset and then call second procedure. still it returns same result. is there any other solution?

Comment: Please see my edit; the next_result call also needs to be removed

Comment: if  I remove next_result ,second query will not work and will not return anything, since I am calling procedure first , and  after that if i use  select queries( or procedure which return recordset)  will not work without using next_result.